# Render jsf data table as it is populated with data

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a data table with binded to a large list. I want to render the data table as that list is fetched, instead of waiting for the entire list to be fetched.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not directly possible in standard JSF implementation. I'd look for the solution in another corner: introduce pagination so that you don't need to wait for zillion of records being fetched, but just only ten, twenty or so. It'll be fetched *much* faster. That's also what decent sites like Google are doing.